# Display dinamically 2 different div on specifics URLs with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm very newbie in JS.
I believe the problem is simple.I want to show/hide the 2 div based of the url.
This is my situation:

I am in https://urlzero.com and I want to display only div1, when I am https://urlone.com and https://urltwo.com I want ti display div2.

```
<div class="div1">

<select size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">

        <option value="https://urlone.com">URL ONE</option>
        <option value="https://urltwo.com">URL TWO</option>

 </select>

</div>

<div class="div2">

<select size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">

        <option value="https://urlthree.com">URL THREE</option>
        <option value="https://urlfour.com">URL FOUR</option>

 </select>

</div>
```

My script

```
window.onload = function() {

if(window.location.href == "https://urlone.com" || window.location.href == 
"https://urltwo.com" ) {

//Hide the element.
document.querySelectorAll('.div1')[0].style.display = 'none';
 }

 if(window.location.href == "https://urlzero.com") {
//Hide the element.
document.querySelectorAll('.div2')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
};
```

It doesn't works!! Show ever the 2 div.
How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: I update !
Show ever 2 div

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the console? Check also, that the URL in `location.href` is exactly the same as in the condition.

Comment: strangely now everything works but with a little bug: when I load the page I see both divs and after 1 second I do not see the div, as if it were slow to put the display: none.

Comment: The code looks like it should work. You could try to use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of `onload` to get the div hidden faster.

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
//my function 
};

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all try to catch all url then use code very similar to bellow code according to your logic .You can change null to undefined or empty depending or your url catchd value..
Hope this will work (JQuery version)..............

```
var $urlOne="https://urlone.com";
var $urlTwo="https://urltwo.com";
var $urlZero="https://urlzero.com";

if(($urlOne =="https://urlone.com" || $urlZero !='') && 
($urlTwo=="https://urltwo.com" || $urlZero!='')) {
 //Hide the element.
$(".div1").hide();
$(".div2").show();
}

if($urlZero=="https://urlzero.com"||$urlZero !='') {
//Hide the element.
$(".div2").hide();
$(".div1").show();
};
```

Comment: I'll try soon. Thanks